# Chrome is auto filling a form with the wrong data

Tags: angularjs, forms, google-chrome, autofill

I have a form on my register page that allows a user to create their account. If the create account request is successful my angular redirects the user to the login view. When the user lands here it auto fills the username/email field with the last name from the previous form.

I am not quite sure why though. The forms both have the same id's and name values so I am very confused on the chrome auto-filling.

Found something out, after registering an account the user is redirected to the login page. It auto fills the lastname into the username box then populates the password correctly. However if you clear the lastname out and login using the proper credentials it updates that Google Save Locker record and from that point on works correctly.

Here are visual examples of what I am seeing.

Registration:
[Filling out form so you can see the last name value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3MWJ.png)

Getting redirected to login page after registration:
[The UI chrome displays after landing on login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMz0S.png)

Link to page for live example:
Website link : app.baileysproject.com

Register form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="RegisterForm">
            <fieldset>


                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="Email" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="stuff.Email" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">A valid email address</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="stuff.FirstName" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">Your first name</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="stuff.LastName" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">Your last name</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-match="stuff.Password" ng-model="stuff.Password" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">Enter a strong password</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="cPassword" name="cPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="stuff.ConfirmPassword" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">Enter the same password again</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="">
                        <button id="CreateAccount" name="CreateAccount" ng-click="CreateAccount()" class="btn btn-info">{{AccountCreatedValue}}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Login form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="Email" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="Email" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">A valid email address</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="Password" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">Strong Password</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="">
                        <button id="Login" name="Login" ng-click="Login()" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: I'm not reproducing this behavior.

Comment: So when you go to my live site that I added here, you create an account and it auto fills your username/email properly from the previous form? I have tested in firefox and it does the same thing as chrome in my case.

Comment: chrome asked me to save the password, which I did, and on the next page, when I picked the username, it filled the password with the correct value.

Comment: That is weird I will try this on another computer because I am asked to save my credentials as well but it sets the username value = to the LastName value from the previous form.

Comment: Also I see that you're in my system now so I will delete your account from my database.

Comment: neither chrome nor firefox pre-fill the username box for me, in both I have to start typing, but when I select one from the list after that, it correctly auto-fills the password.  I even tried to use autofill to populate the registration form from the e-mail, and it correctly filled the firstname and lastname box.  seems like garbage in your cache, not an issue with your forms.

Comment: I get the same result even on another computer.

Comment: maybe others can reproduce your issue, but I don't see it happening, sorry!  good luck either way.....

Comment: My issue is is when I land on the login page for the first time it says do you want chrome to save your password for this site? It populates the values as LastName Password